# Remove a header based on query param with varnish

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, browser-cache, varnish

I want to remove a **cache-control** header from **URL's** with a specific **query params**. e.g. when the query paramater `ajax=1` is present.

e.g

```
www.domain.com?p=3&scroll=1&ajax=1&scroll=1
```

These are getting **cached by chrome browsers** for longer than I would like and I would like to stop that in this specific case. I have tried with `.htaccess` which works for static files however not in action on the URL's mentioned above.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)ajax=1(&|$)
Header unset "Cache-Control"
```

I could use a cache buster in the next website release but difficult in production and worried it would unnecessarily cache lots of files in user browsers so would rather achieve server side.

My server has **Cloudflare** then **NGINX** terminating SSL to **Varnish** then **Apache** with a **Magento 2** instance running on there. So thinking i could possibly achieve this with **NGINX** or **Varnish** configs, or even Cloudflare. I however couldn't seem to find a way to achieve this with page rules in Cloudflare, or could not find examples for Varnish or Nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't want to cache when `ajax=1` is part of your URL params?

You can do this in Varnish using the following VCL snippet:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    if(bereq.url ~ "\?([^&]*&)*ajax=1(&[^&]*)*$") {
        set beresp.http.cache-control = "private, no-cache, no-store";
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    } 
}
```

This snippet will make sure Varnish doesn't cache responses where the URL contains an `ajax=1` URL parameter. It will also make sure any caching proxy that sits in front will not cache, because of the `Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store`.

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I did it on Magento side in end but this is exactly what I was looking for! May come in handy for me in future!